# How to "vacuum" objectbox database file?

Tags: android, kotlin, objectbox

tell me, how can I wait (analogue of VACUUM SQLite) database file? **With saving entity IDs.** I could not find the API. And my code does not work:

```
 val all = boxStore.allEntityClasses
 for ( clazz in all ){
      val box = boxStore.boxFor( clazz )
      val box2 = boxStore2.boxFor( clazz )
      val ids = box.query().build().findIds()
      for ( id in ids ){
           val obj = box[id]
           box2.put( obj )
      }
  }
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID is higher or equal to internal ID sequence: 1 (vs. 1). Use ID 0 (zero) to insert new entities.

good work:

```
val obj = box[id]
(obj as Boxable).id = 0
box2.put( obj )
```

but then I lose ID, maybe I should rely on my ID field and not use @Id for link in my app?

Boxable - abstact class for all entitys in Box with @Id

Comment: Something like VACUUM should not be required with ObjectBox. It should re-use available space after removing entities. What is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: I checked, added a few objects with binary fields, and then remembered the size of the database file. After that, I deleted the objects from the database, but the size of the database did not decrease. The database browser shows 0 objects in the database. But the place they continue to occupy, a similar behavior from Sqlite

Comment: Ah, alright. See and thumbs up https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/552 then.

Comment: It's extremely rare for any program, in any field of computer science to shorten files that it's been working on. They may rewrite them from scratch smaller, but rarely truncate existing files. That's because, for example, in a database, while you may delete the objects, there could be system blocks, like indexes, or other control information near the end of the file, and rearranging that for the rare possibility of reclaiming space is rarely a consideration.